# Objective C Updating Objects In Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

When storing an object in an NSMutableArray, I am having trouble updating the properties of an object, such as the background color or the "hidden" property of a UIView.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
myArray[0] = myView;    

//myArray[0].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
((UIView *)myArray[0]).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

My first attempt is commented out, it doesn't compile because myArray[0] returns type "id" so the compiler doesn't recognize the backgroundColor property.

For my second attempt, I casted it into a UIView, so it recognizes the backgroundColor property, but the code doesn't work (the background is still blue).

Is casting to a UIView creating a copy of my view, and therefore not updating the view I intended to update? How can I get this to work using an array of UIViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to init the array

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then to add an object to the array use

```
[myArray addObject:myView];
```

Finally use your code to change the background color of the first object

```
((UIView *)myArray[0]).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Initializing the array solved my problem. I think forgetting to initialize objects is a common mistake for myself and other new objective-c programmers, probably because I am used to the compiler catching it for me in Java. Thank you for your clear response.